# Specify a range when creating a connection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that I receive daily from a customer that I import data from via a connection. Their data, however, has a blank first row with the column headers in row 2. When creating a connection to this table and importing that way, this causes the very first blank row to be imported as the column headers, and the second row (containing the actual headers) to be imported as data.

Is there a way to omit the first row when creating this connection?

Comment: When you added the connection, did you check the box that says "First Row of data contains column headers"?

I tested based on your question, and with this checked it gave correct headers, unchecked it did as you described

Comment: @DavePenn With the headers box checked, it uses the first row of the target worksheet as headers, which is blank for me, so my headers turn out to be F1-F10 (default for blank cells, I guess?), and the appropriate headers are in the first row of data.

Comment: I think this might be the same as the other question you asked and the file is an older version of excel.  When you tick "First Row of Data contains headers" it ignores any blank rows and looks at the first row of data.  The issue you are having is that Excel is not seeing the first row as blank, which will be due to how the data is exported before it is sent to you.  My guess is that it is excel 2.1.  Can you ask the person sending you the data to export in a different format (such as a later version of excel)?